# Make multiple axios calls using jest

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs, mocking

I am working with rest js using typescript and I am trying to mock multiple API calls using jest for unit testing.

My api calls are in the following format:

```
await axios.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: //api url,
      data: {},
    headers: {}
  })
  .then()
  .catch()
```

I am mocking the axios as follows:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    request: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      data: ['responseData', 'responseData1']
        headers: //response header
    })
  }
});
```

The test case for api call is created as follows:

```
expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalled(); expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ 
method: 'POST', 
url: //api url, 
data: {}, 
headers: {} 
});
```

For multiple API calls, I am mocking it multiple times with different response data but it is taking the last mocked value as the response of all the API calls in the test cases.

for example: for multiple data mocks like:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    request: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      data: ['responseData', 'responseData1']
        headers: //response header
    })
  }
});
```

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    request: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      data: ['secondResponseData', 'secondResponseData1']
        headers: //response header
    })
  }
});
```

when I am running the test cases I am getting the response for all my apis as:

```
data: ['secondResponseData', 'secondResponseData1']
headers: //response header

data: ['secondResponseData', 'secondResponseData1']
headers: //response header
```

instead of:

```
data: ['responseData', 'responseData1']
headers: //response header

data: ['secondResponseData', 'secondResponseData1']
headers: //response header
```

I don't know how to mock the correct response with the correct api call in the test cases. Is there any way that I can mock the correct response with the API calls?

Comment: Check out [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-return-values), you can chain the `...Once` methods to queue up multiple responses.

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work. I says it is not a function to those ...once methods

Comment: Please give a [mre] of that - JavaScript is case sensitive, e.g. `mockResolvedValueOnce`  [definitely exists](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue).

Comment: with mockResolvedValueOnce also I am getting the same response for all my api calls.

Comment: Again, please give a [mre] to illustrate the problem.

Comment: my api call is in the form:

await axios.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: //api url,
      data: {},
    headers: {}
  })
  .then()
  .catch()

I have mocked the axios call as follows:

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    request: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      data: //response data
        headers: //response header
    })
  }
});

I am calling the api as follows:

expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
method: 'POST',
    url: //api url,
      data: {},
    headers: {}
});

Comment: [Edit] the question, include the outcome as well.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited my question. Please go through and suggest on the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Basic usage.

```
import * as axios from "axios";

// Mock out all top level functions, such as get, put, delete and post:
jest.mock("axios");

// ...

test("good response", () => {
  axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {...} }));
  // ...
});

test("bad response", () => {
  axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject({ ... }));
  // ...
});
```

2. With response code.

```
axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 200, data: {...} }));
```

3. Based on parameters.

```
axios.get.mockImplementation((url) => {
    if (url === 'www.example.com') {
        return Promise.resolve({ data: {...} });
    } else {
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, my api calls are not in the format of axios.get... I am using the following format for api calls:

await axios.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: //api url,
      data: {},
    headers: {}
  })
  .then()
  .catch()

because of this format i am unable to write the test case in the forms provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
axiosPostSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockImplementation((url) => {
  if( url === 'www.test.com?key=serverKey') {
    return {
      data: {
        success: false,
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      data: {
        success: true,
      },
    };
  }
});
```